# Powershell How to include username along with processname, etc.,?

Tags: powershell

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | Select-Object -Property LocalAddress,LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,State,@{name='NameofApp';expression={(Get-Process -id $_.OwningProcess).MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription}} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

The above one works perfectly,  Here I want to include the Username as well:

I know that `Get-Process -IncludeUserName` will return the UserName but I don't know how to join this in the above working command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your current query, here is a simple modified approach that will solve your problem:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | ForEach-Object {
    $process = Get-Process -Id $_.OwningProcess -IncludeUserName
    $description = $process.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription
    $username = $process.UserName

    $properties = $_ | Select-Object -Property LocalAddress,LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,State
    $properties | Add-Member -Name "NameOfApp" -Type NoteProperty -Value $description
    $properties | Add-Member -Name "UserName" -Type NoteProperty -Value $username

    $properties
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

**Explanation:**

- Pipe [`Get-NetTCPConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=win10-ps) through to [`Foreach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7).
- Get the process object with [`Get-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7), making sure to include User Names with the `-IncludeUserName` switch.
- Store the descriptions and usernames in separate variables. Not necessary, but I split them up for clarity.
- Get all the TCP connection properties that can be selected immediately with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7) into a [`System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=pscore-6.2.0). This uses the default pipeline variable `$_` from `Foreach-Object`, which is basically the current item from `GetNetTCPConnection`. You can run `Get-Help -Name about_Automatic_Variables` to find out more about pipeline variables, and `Get-Help -Name about_pipelines` for finding out more about pipelines. Unfortunately, these Help files don't contain online versions.
- Add the `NameOfApp` and `UserName` members to the object with [`Add-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member?view=powershell-7).
- Format into a table with [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7) and auto size columns with the `-AutoSize` switch.

You could also use regular `foreach` enumeration as well:

```
& {
    foreach ($connection in Get-NetTCPConnection) {
        $process = Get-Process -Id $connection.OwningProcess -IncludeUserName
        $description = $process.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription
        $username = $process.UserName

        $properties = $connection | Select-Object -Property LocalAddress,LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,State
        $properties | Add-Member -Name "NameOfApp" -Type NoteProperty -Value $description
        $properties | Add-Member -Name "UserName" -Type NoteProperty -Value $username

        $properties
    }
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

The above is wrapping the `foreach` loop inside a script block, so you need to use the call operator `&` to run it. You can read more [About Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7) and [About Script Blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7).